# Finding fast default aliases in Python

Tags: python

Is there a faster way to do the following for much larger dicts?

```
aliases = {
            'United States': 'USA',
            'United Kingdom': 'UK',
            'Russia': 'RUS',
          }
if countryname in aliases: countryname = aliases[countryname]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution is fine, as "in" is 0(1) for dictionaries.

You could do something like this to save some typing:

```
countryname = aliases.get(countryname, countryname)
```

(But I find your code a lot easier to read than that)

When it comes to speed, what solution is best would depend on if there will be a majority of "hits" or "misses". But that would probably be in the nanosecond range when it comes to difference.

Comment: Upped because of the part noting speed depends on the number of hits or misses

Answer (score 2):

If your list fits in memory, dicts are the fastest way to go.  As S.Mark points out, you are doing two lookups where one will do, either with:

```
countryname = aliases.get(countryname, countryname)
```

(which will leave countryname unchanged if it isn't in the dictionary), or:

```
try:
    countryname = aliases[countryname]
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing with .get could be faster than checking and assigning in variable

```
aliases.get(countryname)
```

And if countryname is not exists in aliases it will return None.

Comment: `.get()` can be given a default argument, so `aliases.get(countryname, countryname)` will do the trick concerning the "will return None" problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionary is very large and you expect many of your checks not to find a match, then you might want to consider a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) or one of it's derivatives and allow false positives.

Alternatively, because your keys can be sorted (and/or have a derived values), you could implement a [bisection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) or other [root-finding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) algorithm.

First, I'd figure out exactly how Python implements dictionary look-ups, so you are not just re-inventing the wheel.

Also, a pure-Python implementation of these could be quite slow if it involves a lot of iteration.  Consider Cython, Numpy, or F2Py to get truly optimized.

(if you are dealing with just country names, then I don't think you are dealing with mappings large enough to warrant any of my suggestions), but if you are looking at doing some kind of spell-check implementation, then..

Good luck.